# Prompt user input (arraylist) again if user input does not satisfy condition

Tags: java

I am new to Java. This is a createOrder class that allows users to make order of array of item that users choose from a list. The main concern is that i fail to prompt user to re-input itemID when condition is false. Problem details are listed below.

Identifiers and initialization

```
public static void createOrder(ArrayList <item> list, ArrayList <Stock> stock)
    {
                String addNextItem, itemID = "", invoiceNo = "", idLetter = "";
                final String INVLETTER = "INV";
                double itemPrice = 0.0, totalPrice = 0.0;
                int orderQuantity = 0, idDigit = 0, invDigit = 0, len = stock.size(), itemlen = list.size(), quantityOH = 0, j,k;
                InvoiceNo invoice = null;
                invoice = new InvoiceNo(INVLETTER, invDigit);
```

My do while loop that determines if user wants to make next order again.

```
        do
        {
                //enter invoice no
                checkStockItem(stock); 
                System.out.print("Order No: ");
                System.out.println(invoice.toString());

                System.out.print("Please enter item code: ");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                itemID = input.nextLine();
                idLetter = itemID.replaceAll("[\\d]", "");
                idDigit = Integer.parseInt(itemID.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
                ItemNo no = new ItemNo(idLetter, idDigit);
```

This is where i get stuck at. At the moment I am creating this for loop is to check if:
1. user input matches the stockItemID (from another class).
2. user has exceed his order quota (maximum 10 items in one order).
3. there is duplication of item within an identical order (merge sum of duplicated if found)

```
                    //checks if item number does not match with user input
                    //if yes list out item details for every user input
                    //if no, user has to input itemID again to for validation.

                for(k = 0; k < itemlen; k++)
                {
            if(!list.get(k).getItemID().getItemNo().equals(no.getItemNo()))
                    {
                        for(j = 0; j < len; j++)
                        {
                            if(stock.get(j).getItemNo().getItemNo().equals(no.getItemNo()))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Item Description: [" + stock.get(j).getItemDescription() + "]");
                                System.out.println("Quantity on Hand: [" + stock.get(j).getQuantityOnHand()+ "]");
                                System.out.println("Unit Price: [" + stock.get(j).getUnitPrice()+ "]");
                                System.out.println("Item Description: [" + stock.get(j).getItemDescription() + "]");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                    else
                    {
                        //i want to prompt user input for itemID again if failed
                    }



                //set quantity
                System.out.print("Enter item quantity: ");
                orderQuantity = input.nextInt();
                if(orderQuantity < 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter valid quantity");
                    orderQuantity = input.nextInt();
                }
                item i = new item(no, invoice, itemPrice, orderQuantity, totalPrice, quantityOH);
                list.add(i);
                //asking if the user need to input another item
                System.out.println("Do you want to add next Item Y/N: ");
                Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                addNextItem = input2.next();
                if(!"Y".equals(addNextItem.toUpperCase())&& !"N".equals(addNextItem.toUpperCase()))
                {   
                    System.out.println("Invalid character! Only Y/N");
                }
            }while ("Y".equals(addNextItem.toUpperCase())); //user will continue to add item until addNextItem=='Y'
        }
```

Comment: in else BLock just add `continue;` With naming the do loop like the following

`RootLoop: do{
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
continue RootLoop;
}while(true);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understood your question. Would something like this do the trick?

```
do
{
    //enter invoice no
    checkStockItem(stock); 
    System.out.print("Order No: ");
    System.out.println(invoice.toString());
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get a valid itemID
    Boolean validId = true;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter item code: ");
        itemID = input.nextLine();
        idLetter = itemID.replaceAll("[\\d]", "");
        idDigit = Integer.parseInt(itemID.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        ItemNo no = new ItemNo(idLetter, idDigit);
        //checks if item number does not match with user input
        //if yes list out item details for every user input
        //if no, user has to input itemID again to for validation.

        for(k = 0; k < itemlen; k++)
        {
            if (list.get(k).getItemID().getItemNo().equals(no.getItemNo()))
            {
                validId = false;
            }
        }
    } while (!validId);

    // We now have a valid itemID
    for(j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        if(stock.get(j).getItemNo().getItemNo().equals(no.getItemNo()))
        {
            System.out.println("Item Description: [" + stock.get(j).getItemDescription() + "]");
            System.out.println("Quantity on Hand: [" + stock.get(j).getQuantityOnHand()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Unit Price: [" + stock.get(j).getUnitPrice()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Item Description: [" + stock.get(j).getItemDescription() + "]");
        }
    }

    //set quantity
    System.out.print("Enter item quantity: ");
    orderQuantity = input.nextInt();
    if(orderQuantity < 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid quantity");
        orderQuantity = input.nextInt();
     }
     item i = new item(no, invoice, itemPrice, orderQuantity, totalPrice, quantityOH);
     list.add(i);
     //asking if the user need to input another item
     System.out.println("Do you want to add next Item Y/N: ");
     Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
     addNextItem = input2.next();
     if(!"Y".equals(addNextItem.toUpperCase())&& !"N".equals(addNextItem.toUpperCase()))
     {   
         System.out.println("Invalid character! Only Y/N");
     }
 }while ("Y".equals(addNextItem.toUpperCase())); //user will continue to add item until addNextItem=='Y'
```

Incase it isn't instantly apparent, I added another `do while` loop which will get user input, and validate it (using a similar method to what you had in your `if else` statement, and will loop again if the input was not valid.

Comment: that doesn't even compile

Comment: @BasilBattikhi this is not the main method

Comment: @MackhemChuah Two `Do` Blocks with one `While`  ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi i doubt that works and im still thinking what could be the solution...

Comment: It was meant to have the remainder of his code after. I edited to include his code at the end of mine.

Comment: @MackhemChuah Thanks for Editing the answer in order to be compiling visually